# How is this JSONP without a callback working?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm using a client-side SDK, which creates a script under the hood and attaches it to the `<head>`, and looks like the following:

`<script src="http://foo.com?foo=bar"></script>`

Notice that there's no `callback` parameter.

The response sends back the following (with header `Content-Type: application/javascript`):

`{ document.cookie="something=thing" }`

And it sets the cookie in the browser (I can see when I look at the cookies in the dev tools).

The strange this is, in the URL of the script, there's no callback parameter, as you would normally expect in a JSONP request.

I tried to replicate this behavior by adding a similar script to a local web page and am hitting a local server that returns the same response, but it doesn't set a cookie, unlike the SDK. The SDK itself is pretty simple and I don't see any other magic happening.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? How does it work?

*Edit: here is the internal SDK method and sample response*

```
    _jsonp: function(o, e) {
        var t = document.createElement("script");
        t.type = "text/javascript", t.src = e, t.async = !0, document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t), o.log("SENT JSONP request: " + e)
    },
```

Sample response:

Response headers

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 158
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Response body

`{document.cookie=<redacted>}`

Comment: That's not really a jsonp request. It's really just a javascript file.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, I guess I'm just wondering how that response is getting executed. Additionally, they're calling it a `_jsonp` method under the hood, so I assumed their intent was to make a jsonp request.

Comment: It isn't a jsonp request because the request isn't returning JSONP. it's returning javascript. a jsonp response is also javascript, but not all javascript is jsonp.

Comment: @KevinB Okay, let's pretend their method name `jsonp` is simply a misnomer. We still haven't answered the question about how the response is getting executed.

FWIW, here's the entire minified SDK, which can sorta be read if you have a prettifier in chrome or whatever: http://assets.jetlore.com/js/jltracking.js

Comment: All this code is doing is setting a cookie. when you include it, it sets a cookie. that's... all it is. `{document.cookie=<redacted>}` isn't an object, it's just plain old javascript. It very well could have simply been `alert('Hello World!')` and an alert woulda popped up.

Comment: @KevinB ah I see, just tried it. Feel free to post that as the answer. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the method name in the API source code, it isn't JSONP.

JSONP is a JavaScript program which conforms to the specific format of: Contains only a function call, with one argument, which would be JSON if it was taken out of the JavaScript program and put in a JSON file.

JSONP works by injecting a `<script>` element which loads and executes the JavaScript program.

What you have here is a JavaScript program that doesn't conform to the JSONP format.

It is still a JavaScript program.

Loading with a `<script>` still works.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW, I didn't realize `{ document.cookie="something=thing" }` is valid JavaScript, but lo and behold when I run it in the browser console, it works. Will accept the answer when the time limit expires

Comment: The block around the assignment expression is entirely pointless.